# How to point a shared object to debug information in GDB without altering the files?

Tags: linux, gdb

I have two files - a shared object file and debug information file.
How can I tell GDB to use the debug information file for that shared object without altering the files, file names or creating links?
Is it even possible?

I just want to tell GDB about it, not to change anything.

EDIT: Here is what I am trying to do (on Ubuntu 16.04, x86_64)
I am taking the libc and libc debug information files from my system, and copy them to a new directory. Then, I preload the moved libc to a process and attach to it with GDB.

```
    sudo apt install libc6-dbg
    cp /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so debug_file
    cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 .
    cat << EOF > traceme.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    int main(void) {
      printf("trace me:\nsudo gdb -p %d\n", getpid());
      sleep(20);
      return 0;
    }
    EOF
    gcc -o traceme traceme.c
    LD_PRELOAD=./libc.so.6 ./traceme &
    sudo gdb -p 28163
```

Now, my GDB sessions is this:

```
    (gdb) info sharedlibrary
    From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
    0x00007ff8e77c68b0  0x00007ff8e7919ac4  Yes (*)     ./libc.so.6
    0x00007ff8e7b71ac0  0x00007ff8e7b8f810  Yes         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    (*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
    (gdb) add-symbol-file debug_file 0x00007ff8e77c68b0
    add symbol table from file "debug_file" at
        .text_addr = 0x7ff8e77c68b0
    (y or n) y
    Reading symbols from debug_file...done.
    (gdb) p &main_arena
    $1 = (struct malloc_state *) 0x3c4b20 <main_arena>
    (gdb) p main_arena
    Cannot access memory at address 0x3c4b20
    (gdb) info proc mappings
    process 28163
    Mapped address spaces:

              Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
                0x400000           0x401000     0x1000        0x0 /home/ubuntu/tmp/z/traceme
                0x600000           0x601000     0x1000        0x0 /home/ubuntu/tmp/z/traceme
                0x601000           0x602000     0x1000     0x1000 /home/ubuntu/tmp/z/traceme
                0xff8000          0x1019000    0x21000        0x0 [heap]
          0x7ff8e77a7000     0x7ff8e7967000   0x1c0000        0x0 /home/ubuntu/tmp/z/libc.so.6
          0x7ff8e7967000     0x7ff8e7b67000   0x200000   0x1c0000 /home/ubuntu/tmp/z/libc.so.6
          0x7ff8e7b67000     0x7ff8e7b6b000     0x4000   0x1c0000 /home/ubuntu/tmp/z/libc.so.6
          0x7ff8e7b6b000     0x7ff8e7b6d000     0x2000   0x1c4000 /home/ubuntu/tmp/z/libc.so.6
          0x7ff8e7b6d000     0x7ff8e7b71000     0x4000        0x0
          0x7ff8e7b71000     0x7ff8e7b97000    0x26000        0x0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
          0x7ff8e7d91000     0x7ff8e7d96000     0x5000        0x0
          0x7ff8e7d96000     0x7ff8e7d97000     0x1000    0x25000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
          0x7ff8e7d97000     0x7ff8e7d98000     0x1000    0x26000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
          0x7ff8e7d98000     0x7ff8e7d99000     0x1000        0x0
          0x7ffe53a5a000     0x7ffe53a7b000    0x21000        0x0 [stack]
          0x7ffe53b3a000     0x7ffe53b3c000     0x2000        0x0 [vvar]
          0x7ffe53b3c000     0x7ffe53b3e000     0x2000        0x0 [vdso]
      0xffffffffff600000 0xffffffffff601000     0x1000        0x0 [vsyscall]
```

For some reason, the `main_arena` symbol is not within the mapping of the libc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I tell GDB to use the symbols file for that shared object without altering the files, file names or creating links?

```
(gdb) info shared
```

Will tell you at what address your `foo.so` is loaded. Say it's `$addr`.

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file /path/to/foo.so.debug $addr
```

will tell GDB to add debug symbols for `foo.so` from `foo.so.debug`

**Update:**

> `(gdb) p main_arena`
>   `Cannot access memory at address 0x3c4b20`

I am pretty sure this is a bug in GDB. You are correct: it's not relocating the `.data` section when it should.

Fortunately, there is a workaround:

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file debug_file 0x00007ff8e77c68b0 -s .data 0x7ff8e77a7000
```

(The first address is from `info shared`. The second address is from `info proc map` for the (first) address where `libc.so.6` is loaded.)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work.
It loads the symbols file, but completely ignores the relocation for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: @yannaylivneh I am not sure what you mean by "ignores relocation" -- GDB doesn't care about relocations in the first place. Please edit your question with additional details showing what *isn't* working.

Comment: @yannaylivneh I reproduced your observed behavior, using GDB-7.9, and also recent trunk build: 8.0.50.20171021-git. I am pretty sure it's a bug in GDB. Fortunately there is a workaround. Answer updated.

Comment: @employedrussion actually, the .data address should be the relocated address of the .data section, i.e. 0x7ff8e77a7000 + data_section_vaddr which can be retrieved using readelf: `readelf -S /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so  | grep -w .data`

So, did you open a ticket or should I do it?

Thanks for your help